# parameters for make command

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, makefile, deb

I have a script in bash for building kernels, but I am stuck with a thing. Basically this is my code:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 make -j8 deb-pkg
```

I was wondering if there are any options for indicating where I want the deb packages, because by default the deb packages are always put in a previous folder, as well as an option to indicate my config file, this because I have several config files.

I tried with:

```
make -j8 deb-pkg out_dir=/home/user
```

but it dos not work.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking depends entirely on the contents of the Makefile. Make itself simply calculates dependencies to decide which external programs to run. By convention, there is usually a block of user-overridable configuration variables at the top of the Makefile if indeed customization is supported.

By the looks of it, your Makefile ultimately invokes `dpkg-buildpackage` (or some front end like `debuild`) which in fact does not allow you to change where its output is written. You could perhaps modify the Makefile to move the build artefacts after building, but that is really the topic of a separate question.